# How to fix onedrive corrupt zips with a bash script

Tags: shell-script, zip, binary

Currently onedrive generates zip files that are broken to most software.

https://www.bitsgalore.org/2020/03/11/does-microsoft-onedrive-export-large-ZIP-files-that-are-corrupt

As we can see here, the solution is to use a hex editor. Since I have lots of large files, I want bash script solution...is it possible?

This is a test file freely available:

https://zenodo.org/record/3715394

Comment: Is your question about how to fix the zip file or just how to extract the data from it?

Comment: How to fix it @pmqs

Comment: I have a small Perl script I hacked together a while back to fix these files. Let me tidy it up a bit before I post it

Comment: you are the hero the internet needs @pmqs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue referred to in the link in the question, [Does Microsoft OneDrive export large ZIP files that are corrupt?](https://www.bitsgalore.org/2020/03/11/does-microsoft-onedrive-export-large-ZIP-files-that-are-corrupt),  refers to a problem where zip files created by OneDrive larger than 4Gig have an invalid `Total Number of Disks` field in the ZIP64 `End Central Directory Locator`. The value in this field should be 1, but OneDrive (and it seems Windows send-to-zip) sets it to 0. This makes it difficult/impossible to work with these files using standard unzip utilities.

Running `unzip` against one of these files produces output like this

```
$ unzip -l  onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip
Archive:  onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip
warning [onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip]:  1073742329 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

The link in the original question shows how to manually fix the issue with a hex file editor. Alternatively, see [Fix-OneDrive-Zip](https://github.com/pmqs/Fix-OneDrive-Zip) for a script that will fix these OneDrive zip files. All it does is to set the value to 1 if it is incorrectly set to 0.

Usage is

```
fix-onedrive-zip file1.zip
```

In this instance

```
$./fix-onedrive-zip onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip 

Checking 'onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip'
Updated 'onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip'
```

and checking the zip file can be read

```
$ unzip -l onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip 
Archive:  onedrive-zip-test-zeros.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
1073741824  2020-03-18 14:48   onedrive-zip-test-zeros/file01.dat
1073741824  2020-03-18 14:51   onedrive-zip-test-zeros/file02.dat
1073741824  2020-03-18 14:54   onedrive-zip-test-zeros/file03.dat
1073741824  2020-03-18 14:57   onedrive-zip-test-zeros/file04.dat
1073741824  2020-03-18 15:01   onedrive-zip-test-zeros/file05.dat
---------                     -------
5368709120                     5 files
```

Comment: I've tried with two zip files I had here but it says: `cannot find zip at end of`...

Comment: is it possible i'm been affected by another bug? because i thought it was that one, but my zips i downloaded from the web inteface doesn't work, and your script says that

Comment: Can you create an issue at https://github.com/pmqs/Fix-OneDrive-Zip/issues please? There is either an edge condition that my script doesn't handle, or there is a different issue in your zip files.

Comment: Can do, but let's see if this is a fix for the original question first.  Need to work through the issues that @Freedo is having with the script.

Comment: Onedrive/sharepoint is a disaster! Will destroy account on the first possible oppertunity.